# How to solve matrix differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

How to solve:

$${\frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{\mu}^T}}\left\{\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i(\vec{y_i}-\vec{\mu})^TB^{-1}\right\}}$$

where $a$ and $z_i$ are elements, $\vec{y_i}$ and $\vec{\mu}$ are both $2\times1$ vectors, $B$ is a $2\times2$ matrix.

And is there any software can do such general differentiations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [the matrix calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) notation if you'd like to.
Anyways, you have a derivative of a sum so you can turn it into a sum of derivatives (as I understood $a, \vec{z}, \vec{y_i} $ and $ B$ (or $ B^{-1}$, that doesn't matter) do not depend on $\vec{\mu}$):
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
{\frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{\mu}^T}}\left\{\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i(\vec{y_i}-\vec{\mu})^TB^{-1}\right\}}&=&{\frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{\mu}^T}}\left\{\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i(\vec{y_i}^TB^{-1})-\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i(\vec{\mu}^TB^{-1})\right\}}\\
&=&\frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{\mu}^T}}\left\{-\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i(\vec{\mu}^TB^{-1})\right\}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial{\vec{\mu}^T}}\vec{\mu}^TB^{-1}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{a}\sum^n_{i=1}z_i (B^{-1})^T
\end{eqnarray}
$$